# How to find out what Google account a domain is associated with?

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite, gmail, google

I have a client who needs to add new email accounts to their domain. However, when I access the admin page for the domain, there are no email accounts there. And in the DNS there are MX records pointing to Google.

My client does not know how to add email accounts herself, and I have no idea what Google account the domain is associated with.

Moving the MX records to a new place is not an option, since there are already email accounts on the domain.

So my main problem is how I can find out what Google account a domain is associated with. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Contact Google support. They are actually surprisingly good at helping sort out these kind of issues.

Comment: You really should include information about how to get in touch with them, because most people probably don't know that.

Comment: Indeed x) only thing I found was a support chat that required me to be signed in with the apps admin account, which I obviously don't have as that is my issue in the first place. Thanks for the input though, I'll keep looking :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to forward e-mails from the old e-mails to one central e-mail address that you create, (provided that the customers doesn't use these anymore).

That way they won't miss anything and will receive all of their mail.

Then use the IMAP and POP3 services in a google account for the new e-mail that forwards all the incoming mail from the old e-mails as well as manages the new e-mails as well.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en